# x-editable mode text bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, x-editable

## Hi all!

The x-editablefor type:"text" if mode:'popup' is set there is no possibility to change previously entered text.

If the mode is set to inline, everything works correctly.

Initializing

```
<a href="#" id="editDescrDoc" data-title="Description" data-type="text" data-pk="1">@description</a>

$('#editDescrDoc').editable({
            mode : 'popup',
            pk : 1,
            title : 'Specify description',
            emptytext: 'empty',
});
```

Bootstrap4 is used.

How can this be fixed?

I've searched half of the internet. Found lots of references to js x-editeble which works adapted for bootstrap4, but nothing worked.
I just really want to make the text in popup mode.
Fields with date selection, or list selection in popup mode works correctly, but text input doesn't work.
It works 50% open, but it doesn't allow you to edit the text.